# How to search a mysql data base via php script. (not working)

Tags: php, mysql, search

I can not return results with the php scritp that quires the database and echos results? All i get is fetched data successfully. Any help would be great and thanks.

```
<form action="#" method="get">
search: <input type="text" name="Id"><br>  
<input type="submit" value="delete">
</form>

<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '#####';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$search = $_GET['search'];
if($_GET){
$sql = 'SELECT Id, Employee_Name, 
           Employee_Email
    FROM Blog
    WHERE Id LIKE "%$sql%"';

 mysql_select_db('test');
 $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
 if(! $retval )
 {
 die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "Tutorial ID :{$row['Id']}  <br> ".
     "Title: {$row['Employee_Name']} <br> ".
     "Author: {$row['Employee_Email']} <br> ".
     "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Terrible escaping practices: you should use mysql_real_escape_string. Second, mysql extension will be deprecated, you should be using some PDO. Third, your placeholder variable $sql seems should be $search.

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes don't work in SQL queries. This:

```
$sql = 'SELECT Id, Employee_Name, 
       Employee_Email
FROM Blog
WHERE Id LIKE "%$sql%"';
```

Should be this:

```
$sql = "SELECT Id, Employee_Name, 
       Employee_Email
FROM Blog
WHERE Id LIKE '%$search%'";
```

Also, it's time to stop using the deprecated mysql functions. Switch to [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for MySQL, and switch to [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) if you want to interface with MySQL and other types of databases (MSSQL, Oracle, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
^^^^^^^---one variable name
```

Then have:

```
$sql = 'SELECT Id, Employee_Name, 
           Employee_Email
    FROM Blog
    WHERE Id LIKE "%$sql%"';
                    ^^^^--- wrong variable name
```

e.g. using the wrong variable name, plus having a gaping wide-open [SQL injection attack](http://bobbyt-ables.com) vulnerability.

You're using `$sql` within the string that DEFINES `$sql`, so that inner `$sql` is empty, and your query will be `WHERE Id LIKE "%%"`, which will match everything.

Comment: I have made the changes and now when I search it returns all listings in my database instead of the id number I am searching for. Any ideas would be great. Thanks for all the help, you guys really are great.

Comment: Figured it out. I changed my like statement on an accident and it was looking for something that was not in the data base.